# How do I bind a multi level configuration object using IConfiguration in a .net Core application?

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core, .net-core

I'm trying to bind to a custom configuration object which should be populated by an appsettings.json file.

My appsettings looks a bit like:

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "IncludeScopes": true,
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Debug",
      "System": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Information"
    }
  },
  "Settings": {
    "Foo": {
      "Interval": 30,
      "Count": 10
    }
  }
}
```

The settings classes look like:

```
public class Settings
{
  public Foo myFoo {get;set;}
}

public class Foo
{
  public int Interval {get;set;}
  public int Count {get;set;}

  public Foo()
  {}

  // This is used for unit testing. Should be irrelevant to this question, but included here for completeness' sake.
  public Foo(int interval, int count)
  {
    this.Interval = interval;
    this.Count = count;
  }
}
```

When I try to bind the Configuration to an object the lowest level it works:

```
Foo myFoo = Configuration.GetSection("Settings:Foo").Get<Foo>();
```

`myFoo` correctly has an `Interval` and a `Count` with values set to 30 and 10 respectively.

But this doesn't:

```
Settings mySettings = Configuration.GetSection("Settings").Get<Settings>();
```

`mySettings` has a null `foo`.

Frustratingly, if I use the debugger I can see that the necessary data *is* being read in from the appsettings.json file. I can step down into `Configuration => Non-Public Members => _providers => [0] => Data` and see all of the information I need. It just won't bind for a complex object.

Comment: How does your Settings Class look like?

Comment: How are `Foo` and `Settings` defined?

Comment: @haim770 I've added the class definition.

Comment: Your settings property is `myFoo` but your setting is "Foo"...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your property must match the property names in "appsettings.json".

You must rename your Settings' `myFoo` property into `Foo`, because that's property name in the json file.

Comment: Looks like that was the issue. I ended up naming the properties the same as the object to try and minimize confusion. Now I just have to get the dictionaries (not mentioned above) mapping. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

I've had the same issue a few times.

I resolved my issue by making sure the class properties had {get; set;}.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the JsonProperty(Included in Newtonsoft.Json) Annotation to tell the serializer what to do like below.

```
public class Settings
{
  [JsonProperty("Foo")]
  public Foo myFoo {get;set;}
}
```

Comment: I've checked your code, sorry it doesn't work this way

Comment: You've said that binding with JsonProperty attribute will work but it doesn't. You can look at sample app here https://github.com/akutyrev/SO-Configuration-binding-problem